# How to reduce App's CPU usage in Android phone?

Tags: android, cpu-usage, reduce

I developed an auto-call application. The app reads a text file that includes a phone number list and calls for a few second, ends the call and then repeats.

My problem is that the app does not send calls after 10~16 hours. I don't know the reason exactly, but I guess that the problem is the CPU usage. My app's CPU usage is almost 50%! How do I reduce CPU usage?

Here is part of source code:

```
if(r_count.compareTo("0")!=0) {
    while(index < repeat_count) {
        count = 1;
        time_count = 2;

        while(count < map.length) {
           performDial();   //start call
          reject();                   //end call
          finishActivity(1);
          TimeDelay("60");            // wait for 60sec
          count = count + 2;
          time_count = time_count + 2;
          onBackPressed();            // press back button for calling next number
          showCallLog();
          finishActivity(0);
       }
      index++;
}
```

This is the `TimeDelay()` method source:

```
public void TimeDelay(String delayTime) {

    saveTime = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
    currentTime = 0;
    dTime = Integer.parseInt(delayTime);

    while(currentTime - saveTime < dTime) {
        currentTime =  System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;

    }

}
```

`TimeDelay()` repeats in the while loop for a few times.

Comment: There is no way to tell, given that we don't know what's happening in the functions you're calling, why you are using 50% of the CPU.  If you want an easy way to bring down the average CPU usage you could just increase the time delay to more than 60 seconds.

Comment: Consider using a TimerTask scheduled from a Timer, instead of the while loop.  It is more optimized and you won't have to manage the Thread's sleep/notify calls yourself.

Answer (score 4):

The reason it's using 50% of your CPU is that Android apparently won't let it use 100% of the CPU, which a loop like the one in your `TimeDelay()` ordinarily would. (Or else you have two CPUs and it is in fact using 100% of one CPU.) What you're doing is called a [busy wait](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) and it should be obvious why continually checking a condition will use lots of CPU. So don't do that. Use `Thread.sleep()` instead. Your app will then use no CPU at all during the wait.

Also, for God's sake, why are you passing a string and then `parseInt`ing it, rather than just passing an `Integer` in the first place? :-)

Answer (score 1):

If your method take a long time to finish , especially the while loop. You should put `Thread.sleep(50)` inside your loop. This makes you processor be able to handle other processes.

Your CPU will be reduced. Not sure but you should try.
Hope you get good result.