# Why do Android applications get silently killed when the CPU is near 100%, and how can I avoid this?

Tags: android, cpu-usage

I'm doing some heavy number crunching in an app, it loops forever (occasionally outputting results) and is consuming about 25% to 30% of the CPU. It works fine.

However, I would like to run several copies of this app at the same time.

If I run up to 4 copies, everything works fine, the processor is used slightly below 100%

However, as soon as I start a 5th copy, one of the old copies is silently killed by the OS. The app doesn't receive any pause, stop or destroy signals.

What I would expect to happen, would be the same as running them on a PC. For example, an application alone outputs results in every 10 seconds, and if I run too many of them, once the CPU usage is leveled off, they will take more and more time between results, as the OS is rationing the CPU time among them. On a PC with Windows or Linux I could start even three times the number of copies required for a 100% CPU usage, and they took a much longer time between results, but they worked.

Is there a possibility to achieve the same on an Android phone?

Comment: Try to use foreground service with notification

Comment: This may helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234271/how-to-reduce-apps-cpu-usage-in-android-phone

Comment: I think this is limited by the system. In my developer options on my Huawei Ascend Mate 7, I have the choice to let up to 4 Backgroundprocesses live. Check the developer options, there is a standard mode, but not defined how many processes the standard mode allows